# Phoenix - Invalid CSRF (Cross Site Forgery Protection) token error

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am receiving an Invalid CSRF token error when trying to update (or create) a record. I am using Elixir v1.0.3, Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.3], and Phoenix v0.8.0 (I think, I am not sure how to check Phoenix's version). I am creating a web app mostly following the Phoenix guides and the Elixir Dose Jobsite Example resources. However, when I try to post information from an html form, I get the Invalid CSRF token error. Following the advice given in the error, I added 'x-csrf-token': csrf_token to the action.

edit.html.eex:

```
<h2>Edit Directory</h2>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="<%= directory_path @conn, :update, @directory.id, 'x-csrf-token': @csrf_token %>" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="directory" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Directory</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<%= @directory.directory %>" name="directory" placeholder="Directory" required="required">
    </div>
  </div>
...
```

but I receive the following error:

```
[error] #PID<0.579.0> running Ainur.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: POST /config/directories/2?x-csrf-token=
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (Plug.CSRFProtection.InvalidCSRFTokenError) Invalid CSRF (Cross Site Forgery Protection) token. Make sure that all your non-HEAD and non-GET requests include the csrf_token as part of form params or as a value in your request's headers with the key 'x-csrf-token'
        (plug) lib/plug/csrf_protection.ex:54: Plug.CSRFProtection.call/2
        (ainur) web/router.ex:4: Ainur.Router.browser/2
        (ainur) lib/phoenix/router.ex:2: Ainur.Router.call/2
        (plug) lib/plug/debugger.ex:104: Plug.Debugger.wrap/3
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/error_handler.ex:43: Phoenix.Endpoint.ErrorHandler.wrap/3
        (ainur) lib/ainur/endpoint.ex:1: Ainur.Endpoint.phoenix_endpoint_pipeline/2
        (plug) lib/plug/debugger.ex:104: Plug.Debugger.wrap/3
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/error_handler.ex:43: Phoenix.Endpoint.ErrorHandler.wrap/3
```

As far as I can tell (being new to Elixir, Phoenix, and HTML), "action" is essentially a path and any parameters I place in it will find their way back to the application. And, indeed, I find that x-csrf-token = "" is passed back to the router, so @csrf_token must not be correct. I am not sure exactly where the csrf_token comes from, so I do not know how to reference it (or perhaps I am doing this completely wrong).

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see the version installed, run

```
cat ./deps/phoenix/mix.exs | grep version
```

Which shows you which phoenix you have in the deps directory.

Also, if/when you upgrade to phoenix 0.9.0, things have changed (due to updates to Plug.CSRFProtection), the CSRF works differently using cookies instead of sessions.

From [Phoenix changelog for v0.9.0 (2015-02-12)](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v090-2015-02-12)

> [Plug] Plug.CSRFProtection now uses a cookie instead of session and
>   expects a "_csrf_token" parameter instead of "csrf_token"

To access the token's value, grab if from the cookie, which on the server side looks like

```
Map.get(@conn.req_cookies, "_csrf_token")
```

So for your code, would look something like

```
<h2>Edit Directory</h2>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="<%= directory_path @conn, :update, @directory.id, 'x-csrf-token': Map.get(@conn.req_cookies, "_csrf_token") %>" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="directory" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Directory</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<%= @directory.directory %>" name="directory" placeholder="Directory" required="required">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Now, for completeness, I needed the updated CSRF for requests built purely client side, so here is how I accessed the cookie within javascript, using JQuery cookies, for easy access.  You should be able to see the value in your browser by running the following

```
$.cookie("_csrf_token")
```

Which might return something like

```
"K9UDa23e1sacdadfmvu zzOD9VBHTSr1c/lcvWY="
```

Note in the above, the space, which in phoenix was being url encoded to +, which was still causing the CSRF to fail.  Now is that a bug in Plug, or simply something to be handled, I am not sure, so for now I am simply handling the + explicitly

```
$.cookie("_csrf_token").replace(/\s/g, '+');
```

With access to the CSRF token, we now just need to add the x-csrf-token  to your request header ([thank you ilake](https://gist.github.com/ilake/3656567)).  Here is the code to make it work with an ajax call work (fill in the url and data and response accordingly).

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: 'YOUR URL HERE',
  type: 'POST',
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('x-csrf-token', $.cookie("_csrf_token").replace(/\s/g, '+'))
  },
  data: 'someData=' + someData,
  success: function(response) {
    $('#someDiv').html(response);
  }
});
```

Note that you could send back the _csrf_token as parameter as well, but I prefer the above and it feels cleaner to me.

Final note, I didn't have enough reputation points to properly post a link to jquery cookie, but it should be easy to google.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. It turns out I am running Phoenix 0.8.0, so the code below works, but you have saved me a big headache when I upgrade to 0.9.0!

Comment: Thanks again @a4word, I upgraded to Phoenix 0.9.0 and changed the template to get the token from the cookie. However, strangely enough, it seems to work, but I am still getting a Invalid CSRF (Cross Site Forgery Protection) token error. The token is   `ne0GATpoc/EW6jbIbC7tmfkAWl4qb1opTPWmmfYFTRY=`   (no spaces) and the template creates a url  `POST /config/directories/9?x-csrf-token=ne0GATpoc%2FEW6jbIbC7tmfkAWl4qb1opTPWmmfYFTRY%3D`  I have no idea why Plug.CSRFProtection does not like it. Do you know or should I open another question?

Comment: I changed the name of the token in template from:   `'x-csrf-token": Map.get(@conn.req_cookies, "_csrf_token")`   to:   `'_csrf_token': Map.get(@conn.req_cookies, "_csrf_token")`    and now it works.

Comment: That's right.  See in your POST that the x-csrf-token is added a param on the URL (but it needs to be an HTTP header).  That said the authentication will also check for the _csrf_token param, you yes things will work with that.

Answer (score 21):

On version 0.13 of Phoenix you can do

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="<%= get_csrf_token() %>">
```

because on file `web/web.ex` there's an import of this function.

Comment: Thanks! I was just in the process of upgrading to 0.13.

Comment: Thanks-- that's the only change to the generated web/web.ex from v0.12 -> 0.13

Answer (score 9):

As another solution available since v0.10.0, you can let Phoenix inject the CSRF input for you.

[Example from upgrade guide](http://www.phoenixframework.org/v0.10.0/docs/upgrading-from-v090):

```
<%= form_tag("/hello", method: :post) %>
... your form stuff. input with csrf value is created for you.
</form>
```

That will output the form tag and a few input tags, including the `_csrf_token` one. Results will look something like this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/hello" method="post">
    <input name="_csrf_token" value="[automatically-inserted token]" type="hidden">
    <input name="_utf8" value="✓" type="hidden">
</form>
```

[`form_tag` docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Tag.html#form_tag/2): "for 'post' requests, the form tag will automatically include an input tag with name _csrf_token."

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer on http://phoenix.thefirehoseproject.com. You must create a function to get the csrf token:

web/view.ex

```
def csrf_token(conn) do
  Plug.Conn.get_session(conn, :csrf_token)
end
```

Then retrieve it in the template:

web/template/directory/edit.html.eex

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="<%= directory_path @conn, :update, @directory.id %>" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="<%= csrf_token(@conn) %>">
```

And that's it!

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

- Import `Phoenix.Controller.get_csrf_token:0` to `MyModule.view:0` (under apps/my_app_web/lib/my_app_web.ex):

  `import Phoenix.Controller, only: [get_csrf_token: 0, get_flash: 2, view_module: 1]`
- Add a hidden param in my form:

  `<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="<%= get_csrf_token() %>" />`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the line `plug :scrub_params` causing the problem.
After commenting the line, it worked. But need to make sure to fix it as the app would be insecure without the scrub_params.